Update array of objects as part of $set with arrayFilters in Mongo
I need to update an object in an existing array in Mongo and have it working for the string that needs to be set, but I also need to add an object to an existing array field for that object ?
For example my data could look like this:
{
  _id: "1",
  interested: [
     {
        email: "1@gmail.com",
        status: "pending",
        logs: [
         {
            previousStatus: "pending",
            reviewer: null
         }
        ]
     },
     {
        email: "2@gmail.com",
        status: "pending",
        logs: [
         {
            previousStatus: "pending",
            reviewer: null
         }
        ]
     }
 ]
}

and let's say I need to update the object where email is 2@gmail.com to change the status to 'accepted' and add a new object to the logs array.
My original attempt was:
x.findOneAndUpdate(
     {_id: "1"}, 
     { "$set": 
        { "interested.$[a].status": "included"}, 
       "$push": 
        { "interested.$[a].logs" : 
            { "previousStatus": "pending", "reviewer": "3@gmail.com"
            }
        }
     }, 
     { 
       "arrayFilters": [
         { 
           "a.email" : "2@gmail.com"
         }
        ]
      }
)

but the $push is ignored.
Worst case I could use the findOne to get the current array of logs, append the new object and force that as part of the $set, just wondering if there is an easier solution ?

That query seems to work in the playground: https://mongoplayground.net/p/dPtllIMlLnJ

@Joe You are correct, but it doesn't work in my environment. I noticed we are on mongo 5.x.x  whereas the playground is 6.x.x. I wonder if that's the issue ?

When I test locally with 5.0.26 it also works

You are correct. In my pre hook for mongoose I was using a this._update.$push = {xxx} which was overriding any other push methods. Fixed by changing to this._update.$push = { ...this._update.$push, xxxx}. Sorry for the confusion.

Thanks to @joe for making me realise this was an issue with my code and not the mongo operations
